# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object object] has no 'datepicker'

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, datepicker

[Uncaught TypeError: Object Object] has no method 'datepicker'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16084961/uncaught-typeerror-object-object-has-no-method-datepicker)

Hi - I apologise in advance but I've read the above link where another user had a similar problem to the one I'm now experiencing. It's just the answer is beyond my skills!

Apparently I've imported the jQuery library twice. However I don't know how this was done and how to reverse it!

Can someone explain please what to do in simple terms? I know how to access the WordPress files for my site using FileZilla. I've downloaded 'edit_addons.js' - I just don't know what to replace the below code with! (I'm guessing I do that as that's where the developer tools in Chrome say there's an error?).

// set the datepicker
        $('.edit_addons_datepicker').datepicker({

Comment: Have you loaded jquery ui library?

Comment: You need to edit index.php if I'm not mistaken. I didn't work with wordpress for a long time but in short words you need to find where are jQuery files included and remove last inclusion. It should look something like : <script src="some/paht/or/http/jquery.min.js /> and that line.

Comment: Hi both - Satpal; no I haven't loaded jquery ui library. Never heard of that I'm afraid. Should I? Could it help me to rectify this error?Could it be that a plugin I'm using is bad? 
Goran.it; I'll look in the index.php and see what I can see. Thanks.